# Trigger Next.JS navigation on incoming MQTT message's

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-redux

We are currently creating a nextJS app with the possibility to lissen to incoming mqtt messages. When receiving a mqtt message we want to navigate to a specific page, for example payment page or delivery page.

**Current implementation**

The Mqtt connection is created via the `createApi` function from `Redux Toolkit` and inside a React component (`SetupMqttElement`) we are reading the .data property of the return variable. The data prop contains the incoming messages. The required new url is based on the incoming message flow, but also on another state that replaces the locale in the url when needed.

The above React element is implemented in the base Layout.tsx and should always be included in the app. So from every page there should be the possibility to change the navigation.

```
InitializeMqtt.tsx

import { useGetPathWithLocale } from '@/hooks/usePathWithLocale'
import { useGetSixMqttQuery } from '@/lib/mqtt/six-mqtt'
import { useRouter } from 'next/navigation'
import { useEffect, memo } from 'react'

function SetupMqttElement() {
  const messages = useGetSixMqttQuery().data;
  const router = useRouter()
  const getPathWithLocale = useGetPathWithLocale();

  useEffect(() => {
    return () => {
      if (typeof messages !== "undefined" && messages?.length > 0) {
        if(messages[messages.length - 1].state == "delivery") {
          router.push(getPathWithLocale("/checkout/delivery"));
        } else if(messages[messages.length - 1].state == "payment") {
          router.push(getPathWithLocale("/checkout/payment"));
        } else if(messages[messages.length - 1].state == "done") {
          router.push(getPathWithLocale("/"));
        }
      }
    }
  }, [messages, getPathWithLocale, router])

  return null;
}

export const InitializeMqtt = memo(SetupMqttElement)
```

```
six-mqtt.ts

export const sixMqttApi = createApi({
  baseQuery: fakeBaseQuery(),
  endpoints: (build) => ({
    getMessages: build.query<Message[], void>({
      queryFn: () => ({ data: [] }),
      async onCacheEntryAdded(
        _arg,
        { updateCachedData, cacheDataLoaded, cacheEntryRemoved },
      ) {
        // setup code (fully implemented )
        ...
      }
    }),
  }),
});

export const { useGetMessagesQuery: useGetSixMqttQuery } = sixMqttApi;
```

```
export function useGetPathWithLocale() {
  const pathname = usePathname();

  return useCallback(
    (path: string) => getPathWithLocale(path, pathname),
    [pathname],
  );
}
```

**Current problem**

1. UsePathWithLocate variable causes the component to reload, which then triggers the read of the older mqtt messages. Which result in a false positive page navigation.
2. Reading / navigation of the mqtt messages should only happen when new data is received.
3. SetupMqttElement should never be rerendert. This is possible being fixed by `React.memo()`.